# Adding WCF Web Service to a DotNetNuke site.. Easiest way?

Tags: wcf, dotnetnuke

What kind of project should I use ? I tried a WCF web site and then copied the directory into my DNN site and tried to goto the .svc file without success. Is DNN 6 for 3.5 only?  Should I be running it as integrate and 4.0 in iis ?

The value for the 'compilerVersion' attribute in the provider options must be 'v4.0' or later if you are compiling for version 4.0 or later of the .NET Framework. To compile this Web application for version 3.5 or earlier of the .NET Framework, remove the 'targetFramework' attribute from the  element of the Web.config file.

Answer (score 3):

DNN has supported .NET 4 since DNN 5.4 (or thereabouts) and supports integrated mode in IIS (since early DNN 5.x).

It sounds like maybe you copied over the DNN web.config, which isn't going to work (there a *lot* of stuff in there that DNN needs to work correctly).  Or, maybe you copied the WCF web.config into a subdirectory of the DNN site?  If so, you probably just want to merge those web.config settings with the main config.

The main issue that I've had with getting WCF to work in DNN is making sure that WCF is installed with IIS (so it correctly handles the .svc extension).

Comment: Yes. I copied the entire WCF project.. which is basically the .svc and web.config...  into a subdirectory under the dnn root.. so if that is wrong.. what do I do.. just copy the specific .svc parts in the main dnn web.config ? ill try that .